# Django AJAX requests during regular request not going through

Tags: ajax, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django site with a login webpage. When the login form on the page is submitted, it executes the login view, which runs a function inside it that takes a long time to process (30 seconds or so). So in order to show progress to the client during login, as soon as the form is submitted, a JS function on the login page starts making AJAX POST requests to the server (to a `poll_state` view), which returns the state of the login. It then updates the html of the login page to show the state (like a loading bar).

My question or problem is that when I do the regular `python manage.py runserver` with an NGINX proxy server it works flawlessly. But when I use Gunicorn instead of `python manage.py runserver` the AJAX requests don't go through until the login view has completely processed and returned a response (which is the next webpage). Instead of polling the state of the login, it just returns a bunch of errors for the `poll_state` view after the next webpage has loaded.

When the user submits the login form, the server executes the login view, and simultaneously the client starts polling the server using AJAX requests. Here is the JS code on the login webpage, which sends the requests:

```
      let willstop = 0
      var poll = function() {
        $.ajax({
          url:'http://<my server's ip>/poll_state/',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
              id: $('#id').val(),
          },
          success: function(pollResult) {
            step = pollResult.data
            if (step == 'Done')
              willstop = 1
            $('#step').html(step)
          }
        })
      }
      let refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
        poll()
        if(willstop == 1) {
          clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
        }
      }, 500)
```

It's just sends a request to my server's `poll_state` view (I ommitted my server's address, but can share it if it helps!) every half-second until the login is finished (step == "Done"), and then it just clears the interval (which is kinda redundant since it redirects to a new page anyway).

And the `poll_state` view:

```
def poll_state(request):
    """ A view to report the progress to the user """

    data = 'Fail'
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        data = loggingInSteps[request.POST.get('id')]
    else:
        data = 'This is not an ajax request'

    result = {'data': data}
    return JsonResponse(result)
```

`loggingInSteps` is a global dict on the server with the steps for all the clients. Each client has a unique id, which is the key and the value is the step the client is on in the login process. The key-value pair gets deleted upon redirect.

The server I am running this on is a 64-bit Ubuntu DigitalOcean droplet, so it's supposed to be my production server. I followed [this tutorial](http://adambeagle.com/blog/deploying-django-17-ubuntu/) to set up the server, so my NGINX configuration is:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name cume;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /static/ {
    alias /home/mikmaks/dev/CUNYsecond/cume/static/;
  }
}
```

And I start Gunicorn either like this `gunicorn config.wsgi --bind 127.0.0.1:8000` or as a daemon like this: `gunicorn config.wsgi --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 --daemon --log-file ~/dev/logs/cume_gunicorn.log --workers=3`
Either version doesn't work.

Does anybody know if Gunicorn can take AJAX requests from the same client as it's processing a normal request from it? Maybe the problem isn't Gunicorn, but is my NGINX configuration. Thank you so much for the help. I'll gladly provide any code or additional info if necessary :)

Comment: What are the errors you are referring to - are they in the browser console?

Comment: Yes, the browser console throws 500 Internal Server errors and the terminal window gives errors that I'm trying to access something that doesn't exist (a key-value pair in a dict), but it does exist, just the key-value pair it's trying to access in the `poll_state` view gets deleted after the login finishes.

The errors only appear after the next page is loaded! (sorry, I thought this was important to add)

Comment: need 3 things added to the question
1. Your nginx config
2. Where your run `python manage.py runserver`, local or production server?
3.What is your gunicorn worker configuration

Comment: Made the edits, I hope they help :)

Comment: Can you post the python code snippet that fails? I bet it has something to do with multiple processes on server (when you user runserver, it is just one process)

Comment: I added the code! hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an asynchronous worker (in my case, I used `gevent`) worked! Now Gunicorn processes multiple requests at a time, i.e. the request that was blocking everything (to the login view) is being processed asynchronously, so the AJAX requests go through.

I start Gunicorn up now with: `gunicorn config.wsgi --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 -k gevent --worker-connections 1001 --workers=3`. The only thing is now, when the load is split amongst 3 workers,  it doesn't update that well, but with 1 worker it works perfectly. I'll have to figure it out some more to see if I can get it to work with 3 workers.

Thank you, Alex, for helping!

Comment: Glad to hear I could help! But sounds like you figured it out by yourself!

Answer (score 2):

`loggingInSteps is a global dict on the server with the steps for all the clients` may be a problem if you have more that one process handling the request. The dictionary can be updated in one process, but not in another. Perhaps switching to single-process mode (`--workers=1` ?) will resolve your problem.

Alternatively, you can redesign your application and get rid of global dict to make it work in multiprocess environment

Comment: I tried commenting out the global dict part and just returning a string back in the `poll_state` function. I also set `workers=1`, but neither did anything. It seems to be something else. At the end of the login view and `poll_state` view I print out the JSON, which then also gets sent as the response of the view. In the terminal window, it first prints out the JSON from the login view and then it prints out the string from the poll_state view like twenty times (or however many times it sent the AJAX request). It's like it queues the AJAX requests until the login request is finished.

Comment: I've been looking up things related to Gunicorn and is it, perhaps, the fact that I am using synchronous workers? Should I be using `gevent` or `eventlet` workers, which are asynchronous?