# AJAX requests not working properly with gunicorn when logged out from server

Tags: ajax, django, gunicorn, gevent, ubuntu-server

I've made my first django application deploy on server this weekend. It was clear VPS server so I have to install PostgreSQL, PostGIS, set virtualenv and so on. It takes some time to make application works.

On django development server everything works fine, but when I deployed my app with gunicorn (cooperates with Nginx) on VPS server AJAX requests not working properly. I have three AJAX request sending right after the other. And only one or two requests have returned value. So I found gevent and this thread ([Django AJAX requests during regular request not going through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435485/django-ajax-requests-during-regular-request-not-going-through/41449049#41449049)) and run gunicorn with this command:

```
gunicorn myapp:wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:9000 -k gevent --worker-connections 1001 --workers=3
```

and it works. All requests return values and everything looks ok. So I put process to background with and logged out from server.

But everytime when I log out from server the requests stop work. The behavior is the same as firstime without gevent. Could be the problem of activating virtual environment, setting or this is standard behaviour of Ubuntu as server?

I don't even know where should I find solution so I will be glad for any help.

Comment: How do you put a process to the background? I suggest you use supervisor, which will run and restart gunicorn if needed.

Comment: No, I just pres CTRL+Z and wrote bg. Is it probably bad how I see from dahrens answer. The server and app is still working but request not working properly. So I didn't expect problems with bad putting to background

Comment: So if I understand well it is because gevent must be monitored by Supervisor (or something like that) and it is the reason why app still works but request are not.

Comment: Try switching to waitress instead of gunicorn. https://blog.etianen.com/blog/2014/01/19/gunicorn-heroku-django/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently stop the process on logout. You need a process manager that monitors the process. Read the [gunicorn docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#monitoring) for a lot of possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried some monitors but I have no much time so I will continue today at night.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). It will make sure gunicorn runs, and restart if it crashes. Install it with `sudo apt-get install supervisor`

Let's assume you have a website called test, you could use the following `test.config` (inside `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/`)

```
[program:test]
directory=/home/test/www
command=/home/test/commands/start
user=nobody
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stopsignal=QUIT
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

Where `/home/test/www` is the location of your django application (you can change it of course), and `/home/test/commands/start` is a script where you tell gunicorn to run (the command you pasted).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it today

Comment: It's not working. I saw in documentation then it is not for python 3. Sorry for that. I didn't write that information. I will continue with trying next options

Comment: Supervisor doesn't support python3, but your website can use it. I've used this combination before